# Exactness of a direct image of a open inmersion.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-categories

Let $i:U\to X$ the inmersion of an affine open subscheme $U=Spec\,A$ in a quasi-compact quasi-separated scheme. Let $i^*$ denote the direct image functor from A-mod. to $Qcoh(X)$. Is it an exact functor? and why is it or is not?

Comment: In general, you have no control over the stalks outside $U$ which causes problems as shown in the linked duplicate.